# how to add LogAnalyticsWorkSpace extension to VM using Python SDK in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine, azure-python-sdk

I have created Log Analytics workspace in azure. Now to want to attach it as an extension to VM using Python sdk. I have followed the documentation and getting error as follow.

class 'azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError'> occurred.

Can someone help me in this please.

Below is the approach I have tried using compute management client.

```
   extension = compute_client.virtual_machine_extensions.begin_create_or_update(
        "MyRG",
        "MyVMName",
        "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent", ##VMExtension name
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "location": "eastus",   
             "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",         
             "type_handler_version": "1.0",            
             "auto_upgrade_minor_version": True,
             "settings": {
               "workspaceId": "XXXXX"
                },
             "protected_settings": {
                "workspaceKey": "XXXXX"
                }            
        }
    ).Result()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and successfully created Log-Analytics-WorkSpace extension to VM using python:**

**Code:**

I tried with **`ComputeManagementClient`** and **`DefaultAzureCredential`** method to ***begin_create_or_update.*** Make sure with parameters and resources are correct state.

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


subscriptionid = "<subscription id>"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
compute_client=ComputeManagementClient(subscription_id=subscriptionid,credential=credential)
extension = compute_client.virtual_machine_extensions.begin_create_or_update(
   resource_group_name="<resource group>",
        vm_name="<vname>",vm_extension_name="MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",extension_parameters=
        {
             "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
             "location":"eastus",       
             "type_handler_version": "1.0",            
             "auto_upgrade_minor_version": True,
             "settings": {
               "workspaceId": "7c950e4f-5c9b-4205-ba79-278cd22bd220"
                },
             "protected_settings": {
                "workspaceKey": "TlLvMVn55RQEHtWBJUSvmbYyaVeev4srp1Vu5ZF/dh2paVI9qrQ/8P4rnEGjmPkHD8LbOpQHKUOhSHMz2r/v2A=="
                }               
        }
    )   

print("Extension is created")
```

**Console:**

I executed the above code it created log-analytics extension successfully in my environment.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure-content/log-analytics-azure-vm-extension.md at master · uglide/azure-content (github.com)](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-vm-extension.md).

Comment: hi Venkat, Regarding the last line "Make sure before running code your virtual machine is connected to log analytics workspace.", I couldnt get this. I thought the script connects log anaytics workspace as an extension to VM. Should we explicitly do this apart from running the script ?

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-vm-extension.md#enable-the-vm-extension-in-the-azure-portal

Comment: thanks @venkat. It worked. Thinking from an automation front, I felt this is additional step to do manually or by powershell to connect VM to log analytics. The python script comes at a later part.

Comment: Hi @venkat,  I read through the reference link you provided. But I couldnt comprehend the difference between connecting the VM to log analytical workspace  and what the script is doing. If workspace is already connected to VM what is point of the script adding workspace extension to VM.  Can you please clarify.

Comment: I gather info from that reference and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python.